# Best my.cnf configuration for a 8GB MySQL server with MyISAM use only

Tags: mysql, php, performance, drupal, myisam

I am preparing a large Drupal 6.x based installation and have setup a dedicated MySQL server with 8GB of RAM. Drupal 6.x uses only MyISAM engine and there will be around 500 concurrent users using the site through two web nodes.

Here is a dump of mysql tuning primer analysis, I took it early in the morning as I am not sure if this should be run during high usage or not: http://pastie.org/3279741.

I am not very experienced in mysql configuration, so I am looking for help in determining the right configuration for my.cnf file so that I can sustain the amount of load. I need this on a pretty urgent basis so not looking for resources for understanding (at least not now!).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That tuning primer script seems to think you have 16GB, not 8GB.

Comment: with Higher version of MySQL InnoDB is Default and perform more better than the MyISAM so why you are going with MyISAM if it is not the restriction to use the MyISAM.The Higher Version of MySQL(5.5) Perform really well they have built-in plugins and provide better Performance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know the drupal.
But as you asked you need dedicated MyIsam MySql configuration.
For MyIsam i have some recommendations as

```
key_buffer_size
```

Size of the Key Buffer, used to cache index blocks for MyISAM tables.
 Do not set it larger than 30% of your available memory, as some memory
 is also required by the OS to cache rows. Even if you're not using
 MyISAM tables, you should still set it to 8-64M as it will also be
 used for internal temporary disk tables.**So You should set it from 2GB to 3GB**.

```
read_buffer_size
```

Size of the buffer used for doing full table scans of MyISAM tables.
Allocated per thread, if a full scan is needed..**You should set it to 8MB to 16MB .**

```
read_rnd_buffer_size
```

When reading rows in sorted order after a sort, the rows are read
through this buffer to avoid disk seeks. You can improve ORDER BY
performance a lot, if set this to a high value.
Allocated per thread, when needed.

```
bulk_insert_buffer_size
```

MyISAM uses special tree-like cache to make bulk inserts (that is,
INSERT ... SELECT, INSERT ... VALUES (...), (...), ..., and LOAD DATA
INFILE) faster. This variable limits the size of the cache tree in
bytes per thread. Setting it to 0 will disable this optimisation.  Do
not set it larger than "key_buffer_size" for optimal performance.
This buffer is allocated when a bulk insert is detected.**Set it to 512 MB to 1GB.**

```
myisam_sort_buffer_size
```

This buffer is allocated when MySQL needs to rebuild the index in
REPAIR, OPTIMIZE, ALTER table statements as well as in LOAD DATA INFILE
into an empty table. It is allocated per thread so be careful with
large settings.**So You should set it to 2M**

```
myisam_max_sort_file_size
```

The maximum size of the temporary file MySQL is allowed to use while
recreating the index (during REPAIR, ALTER TABLE or LOAD DATA INFILE.
If the file-size would be bigger than this, the index will be created
through the key cache (which is slower).Set it to as you need.

```
myisam_repair_threads
```

If a table has more than one index, MyISAM can use more than one
thread to repair them by sorting in parallel. This makes sense if you
have multiple CPUs and plenty of memory.Set it to 1.

```
myisam_recover
```

Automatically check and repair not properly closed MyISAM tables.

Comment: If you need any other help regarding the MySQL server setting Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Drupal (even 6.x) prefers to run on InnoDB.  MyISAM is the default, yes, but that's simply because of a conscious effort to support hosters that don't offer InnoDB--see http://drupal.org/node/301362 .  Consequently, I'd very strongly encourage you to reconsider your exclusive use of MyISAM.

One caveat does apply to this: the search_* tables use FULLTEXT indexes, which are not compatible with InnoDB.  Leave those MyISAM, or better yet, replace their functionality with something like Apache Solr.

If you do use mysqltuner.pl after converting to InnoDB, unless it has been recently updated, it won't bother to tell you to set innodb_buffer_pool, which is the biggest performance key for InnoDB.

The conversion process from MyISAM to InnoDB is lossless and relatively quick; it's just a simple `ALTER TABLE`sometable`ENGINE=InnoDB`.  Be sure to have set innodb_buffer_pool before you do this or you may be in for a long wait!

Lastly, I wanted to get in a quick mention that a hosting provider with experience with large-scale Drupal deployments would take care of most or all of these steps for you.  Consider talking to BlackMesh--for whom I work--or another host active in the Drupal community.  They will likely be able to offer additional Drupal-specific support and scaling advice as you continue to grow your site.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you want to run it under real load, not fake load.  The numbers are about how things have performed in the past, so if that isn't like the real load, they won't help as much as they might.
2. Just do what mysqltuner tells you to.

If you don't have time to learn the details of tuning the product, and want to just follow the best practices, mysqltuner is for you!  It does exactly that: capture best practice recommendations, and tell you what to change based on your real use.